# Source for/availability of Spanish-language California History books?

Tags: traducción, historia

I hope this is not an unwanted question for this forum, but I don't know where else to ask it.

I would like to translate some early California history books, memoirs, letters, etc. written in Spanish into English. I am interested in material that has not yet been translated into English. Of particular interest would be the the early 1800s, but any and all of it interests me.

Does anybody know of a source where I could find such books/documents?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a good fit here. The community decided early on that our questions should be focused on the Spanish language, and that questions about resources are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Quizá encuentres algo en los archivos digitalizados disponibles en la página de la Biblioteca Nacional de España (Biblioteca Digital Hispánica).

Comment: Would that just have books from Spain? I'm more interested in writings by Mexicans.